# Remove review stars if no reviews in WooCommerce shop and archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, rating

I want to not display the stars on products in the Shop page loop. My current code doesn't work...

I'm working on a WooCommerce website with Astra.

```
function no_stars_if_no_reviews() {
    global $product;
    if ($average = $product->get_average_rating()) :
if($average > 0) {
remove_filter(get_average_rating);
}
}
```

I just want to remove the filter when no reviews are there, but keep it otherwise. Once again, this is for the Products page, NOT single.

Comment: Why the assignment wrapped in if()? And did you define a constant with the name `get_average_rating` anywhere? If not, you probably meant to use a text literal in that place, not a constant.

Comment: function no_stars_if_no_reviews() {
     global $product;
     $average = $product->get_average_rating();
        if($average > 0) {
     remove_filter(get_average_rating);}
    }

Would this work better?

Comment: I got it working! For anyone out there, this worked!

function no_stars_if_no_reviews() {
 global $product;
 $average = $product->get_average_rating() ;
    if($average > 3) {
  echo ('<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>');
 }
 else { return; }
}

add_action ( 'astra_woo_shop_title_after', 'no_stars_if_no_reviews');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the following, to remove rating stars from shop and archive pages when no reviews:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'conditionally_remove_loop_rating', 4 );
function conditionally_remove_loop_rating(){
    global $product;

    if( ! ( $product->get_review_count() > 0 ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: `remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );`
seems this is not working anymore.
Can be replaced?

Comment: @ВладимирКятипов It still works on last WooCommerce version see on the [`content-product.php` template file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.2.1/templates/content-product.php#L54)… If it doesn't work for you it can be due to your theme customizations or a plugin…

Comment: Hi, I have recently tested this code, and it isn't consistent. For instance, from the products category page, sometimes a product doesn't have reviews, stars are hidden, but when clicked on the product itself, the detail page indeed shows reviews.